# Connecting to Oracle on a Vagrant box from OS X

Tags: oracle10g, centos, osx-lion, vagrant, centos6

I have a Oracle 10g installed on a CentOS 6 Vagrant box (VM) running on OS X Lion. On the CentOS I can run `sqlplus` for the oracle user (not root). I can ping to my Vagrant box using it's IP from `OS X` and vice-versa. I am also forwarding the port 1521 from `CentOS` to port 1521 on `OS X`.

I want to connect to the Oracle on my VM using SQLDeveloper on my OS X. I keep getting the following error

> Status : Failure -Test Failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have something like this in your Vagrant file:
`config.vm.forward_port 1521, 1521`

Then you should just need to:
`sqlplus system/manager@//localhost:1521/xe`

If that fails, make sure the Oracle listener is started on the Virtual machine.
(do a `netstat -ln | grep 1521` on the virtual machine)

Don't use the virtual machines IP address to connect to Oracle.
Vagrant uses NAT, so you should not be able to ping the virtual machine

If all else fails, use this:
https://github.com/rjdkolb/vagrant-ubuntu-oracle-xe